# Import "django.urls" could not be resolved from source

Tags: python, django, django-urls

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("" , views.index, name="index")
]
```

django.urls part

> Import "django.urls" could not be resolved from source

I tried everything but it didn't work

Comment: Are you using a version of Django less than 2?

Comment: i dont know how can i control it ?